# How to implement/override Protected List.Contains() for a custom Collection Class using a property of item

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, collections

I'm not entirely sure that my wording is correct on the title above. I guess the easiest way to explain it is to put the code below for reference and then give what I'd like to have as the expected behavior.

---

```vb
Public Class Domino
    Public ReadOnly MinimumSideValue As Integer = 0
    Public ReadOnly MaximumSideValue As Integer = 6

    Public Property key As Integer
    Public Property Side1 As Integer
    Public Property Side2 As Integer

    Public Sub New(side1Value As Integer, side2Value As Integer)
        Me.Side1 = side1Value
        Me.Side2 = side2Value
        ' Key should be a two digit number. side values 5 and 1 -> 51
        Me.key = Integer.Parse(Side1.ToString & Side2.ToString)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Convert.ToString(Me.key)
    End Function

End Class
```

---

```vb
Public Class DominoCollection
    Inherits System.Collections.CollectionBase

    Public Sub AddDomino(newDomino As Domino)
        ' Not sure if I should be calling Contains on the Protected List object
        If Not List.Contains(newDomino) Then
            List.Add(newDomino)
        End If    
    End Sub

    Public Function Contains(objDomino as Domino) As Boolean
        ' Need to check if a domino that has the same key already exists
        Dim found As Boolean = False
        For i = 0 To List.Count - 1 'This will fail if the list is empty...
            If DirectCast(List.Item(i), Domino).key = objDomino.key Then found = True
        Next
        Return found
    End Function    

End Class
```

---

The fist code listing is the class that will have multiple instances created. The second class is the collection that will contain instances of the first class. The collection should not contain duplicate items. So when I call the contains method on the built-in protected `List` object from the CollectionBase I'd like it to search the list of items looking for a duplicate with the same value in the `key` property of the first class.

I'm not entirely sure if I can override the List.Contains method because it's a protected object and/or if I should really be creating my own contains method. I tried creating my own .Contains method, but it fails if the list is empty.

---

### EDIT

I know that my code isn't in C#. However since it's .NET, C# answers would help just as much as VB would.

---

### EDIT: Revised Code

After seeing some of the solutions below I've got the following that so far is looking like it will work as I wanted. However I'm not sure I implemented the `Item` property correctly. I haven't tested it as of yet because I'm not to the point of being able to use it in the rest of the application, I'm just trying to get a framework down.

```vb
Friend Class DominoCollection
    Private domCol As Dictionary(Of Integer, Domino)

    Public ReadOnly Property Keys As System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of Integer, Domino).KeyCollection
        Get
            Return domCol.Keys
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Values As System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of Integer, Domino).ValueCollection
        Get
            Return domCol.Values
        End Get
    End Property

    Default Public Property Item(DominoKey As Integer) As Domino
        Get
            If domCol.ContainsKey(DominoKey) Then
                Return domCol.Item(DominoKey)
            Else
                Throw New KeyNotFoundException(String.Format("Cannot find key {0} in internal collection"))
            End If
        End Get
        Set(value As Domino)
            If domCol.ContainsKey(DominoKey) Then
                domCol.Item(DominoKey) = value
            Else
                Throw New KeyNotFoundException(String.Format("Cannot find key {0} in internal collection"))
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Default Public Property Item(domino As Domino) As Domino
        Get
            If domCol.ContainsKey(domino.key) Then
                Return domCol.Item(domino.key)
            Else
                Throw New KeyNotFoundException(String.Format("Cannot find key {0} in internal collection"))
            End If
        End Get
        Set(value As Domino)
            If domCol.ContainsKey(domino.key) Then
                domCol.Item(domino.key) = value
            Else
                Throw New KeyNotFoundException(String.Format("Cannot find key {0} in internal collection"))
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        domCol = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Domino)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Add(dom As Domino)
        If Not domCol.ContainsKey(dom.key) Then
            domCol.Add(dom.key, dom)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function Contains(dom As Domino) As Boolean
        Return domCol.ContainsKey(dom.key)
    End Function

    ' flexibility:
    Public Function Remove(dom As Domino) As Boolean
        If domCol.ContainsKey(dom.key) Then
            domCol.Remove(dom.key)
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function Remove(key As Integer) As Boolean
        If domCol.ContainsKey(key) Then
            domCol.Remove(key)
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function Count() As Integer
        Return domCol.Count
    End Function

    Public Sub Clear()
        domCol.Clear()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the central importance of `Domino.Key`, I think a class which uses a Dictionary would make things easiest.  Since your code is always looking for that to decide if a `Domino` object exists etc, a Dictionary will help detect that and prevent dupes etc.

```vb
Friend Class DominoCollection
    Private mcol As Dictionary(Of Integer, Domino)

    Public Sub New()
        mcol = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Domino)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Add(dom As Domino)
        If mcol.ContainsKey(dom.key) = False Then
            mcol.Add(dom.key, dom)

        ' optional: replace - dont know if this is needed
        Else
            mcol(dom.key) = dom
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function Contains(dom As Domino) As Boolean
        Return mcol.ContainsKey(dom.key)
    End Function

    ' flexibility:
    Public Function Remove(dom As Domino) As Boolean
        If mcol.ContainsKey(dom.key) Then
            mcol.Remove(dom.key)
            Return True
        End If
        Return False
    End Function

    Public Function Remove(key As Integer) As Boolean
        If mcol.ContainsKey(key) Then
            mcol.Remove(key)
            Return True
        End If
        Return False
    End Function

End Class
```

---

For an Item and Items:

```
Public Function Item(key As Integer) As Domino
    Return mcol(key)
End Function

Public Function Items() As List(Of Domino)
    Return New List(Of Domino)(mcol.Values)
End Function
```

`Items` hides the `KeyValuePair` typically required to iterate and allows you to do a simple For/Each loop on the collection (of needed):

```
Dim doms As New DominoCollection

doms.Add(New Domino(1, 2))
doms.Add(New Domino(2, 3))
doms.Add(New Domino(4, 6))

For Each d As Domino In doms.Items
    Console.WriteLine("s1:{0} s2:{1} k:{2}", d.Side1, d.Side2, d.key.ToString)
Next
```

Output

> s1:1 s2:2 k:12
>   s1:2 s2:3 k:23
>   s1:4 s2:6 k:46

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using the `Friend` modifier in the class declaration rather than using the `Public` modifier?

Comment: Public makes it accessible outside the assembly which you probably don't need.

Comment: One more question. How would I get the `Item` property of the internal dictionary to be accessible through the new class?

Comment: `Public Function Item(key As Integer) As Domino`  your whole thing will be key based (I dont know how to play Dominoes, so I cannot anticipate what you might want/need like if those was Cards or something)

Comment: as far as the Key goes, I didn't want them to be added, I wanted it to produce the two digit number, the left digit is side1 and the right digit is side2 ` s1:4 s2:6 -> k:46`. on a secondary note I implemented the `Items` as a Default property rather than a function. I'll edit my post in a moment.

Comment: ahh!  I misunderstood what you were doing with the key.  I made Items a function on purpose; as a property be sure it is ReadOnly or has an empty setter

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you definitely should either inherit from a generic collection class or implement a generic collection interface.

I'm not sure on the exact syntax for VB, but I think instead of `List.Contains` you want to use the Linq extension `Any` with a lambda. I think it goes something like this:

```
List.Any(Function(d as Domino) d.key = newDomino.key)
```

This will return true if any of the elements inside `List` matches the key.

Comment: While this looks like a viable answer to my question specifically, I feel like the answer provided by Plutonix will be easier for me to implement as I am a little more familiar with Dictionary objects. I has to google search what a lambda is and I'm still not completely sure how they work .

Comment: Yeah a dictionary is probably the best choice in this case if you don't care about the order of the items in the collection.

Comment: @BrandonB `this looks like a viable answer` if so, you should upvote his answer to acknowledge the effort and attempt.

Comment: I'm getting to it...   :P